# Why does my electron-forge with webpack template makes distributables with empty node_module folders?

Tags: webpack, electron, node-modules, electron-forge

I'm recently trying out **electron 12** with webpack bundler, and lately realized every time It builds a distributable with `yarn make` the build's node_module folder is empty.Hence, since I expose some modules through `ContextBridge` from preload.js, the app crashes and throws a missing error message.

Regardless, It works after I manually copy the entire node_module folder into it.

Comment: Are your dependencies `devDependencies`? devDependencies aren't included in the distributable

Comment: No, I have my intended devdependencies apart. This is my list of dependencies.
`"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }`

In the dist, dependencies such as qrnode are imported from the preload script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default configuration with `electron-forge` and Webpack bundles your main/preload/renderer code.

This has mostly a positive impact:

- More compact distributables without all the cruft that that exists in `node_modules`
- If you're using `nodeIntegration: false` there is no `require` in the renderers so bundling the code is a requirement if you want to use dependencies
- Faster startup times because:

  - `require`'ing hundreds or possibly thousands of individual files can be slow
  - Your code is minimised and smaller so less code for Chrome to parse at startup

What are the negatives?

- Not all node.js modules work with bundling
- Native modules are often incompatible with bundling

Comment: Now that's why I'm unable to use qrcode and other modules on renderer. Thank you.

Comment: What would be the solution if I have Native modules

Comment: Usually you can add them to your bundlers `externals` configuration and they'll be left in `node_modules`